# Export all users NOT in AAD security group with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I need to export all users who are not a member of a certain security group to a CSV file, using PowerShell.

Pretty straight forward, I know, but I can only find methods of exporting users who do meet certain criteria, not methods of exporting users who don't. I found one method that works but only with Active Directory.

I'm currently using this to pull all users:

```
Get-MSOLUser -all | Where-Object { $_.isLicensed -eq "True"} | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv C:\365\users.csv
```

And am aiming to get something like this:

```
Get-MSOLUser -all | Where-Object { $_.isLicensed -eq "True", isNotMemberofGroup ""} | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv C:\365\users.csv
```

I am unsure how to add an additional condition that only pulls members that are not in a certain security group, using the following logic - dump upn to csv if user is licensed, and if user is not member of group xxx.

Comment: Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be 
[put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please [edit] the question and add a [mcve]: a code, actual output, desired output (obfuscate sensitive data in your examples).

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. I believe I have met the criteria.

Comment: Compute `$certaingroupmembers = (Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $certaingroupID -MemberObjectTypes user).ObjectId` and then use `…Where-Object { $_.isLicensed -eq "True" -and  $_.ObjectID -notin $certaingroupmembers}`.

Comment: if you change the -eq to -ne for not equal does that meet your test? of users that aren't licensed?